# Why can i not print to a network attached printer from Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, printing, samba, raspberrypi

I am using my Rasberry Pi as a print server using Samba. I have followed [this tutorial](http://andrum99.blogspot.dk/2013/06/getting-hp-laserjet-1018-printer.html), but i cannot print from my ubuntu laptop. I have added it as Windows Printer via Samba. But i get the  NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED error when i try to print. If i add credentials when i add the printer (i use my raspberry pi username and password (which should be added to the right group)) i get: "Not authorized, The password may be incorrect."

I know i could just as well post this in a raspberry pi forum, but since the problem is only with Linux/Ubuntu i thought i would post it here...

Comment: Seems to be in the Samba Configuration.
Can you verify if your Samba printer share looks like this?

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

[printers]

   comment = All Printers

   browseable = yes

   path = /tmp

   printable = yes

   public = no

   writable = no

   create mode = 0700

You may want to take a look at this as well: http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/raspberry.nsf/id/JUND-95VRCY

Comment: If i change it to what you write i cant even browse it. I can add it directly if i put the ip in, but i still get the same error as above... Im confused. I think its strange that it doesn't work in Ubuntu when it works in Windows...

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me were to put the following in the smb.conf on the raspberry pi:

```
use client driver = yes
```

Comment: Oh yeah right. That generally applies on almost every samba printer share. I forget about this.

Comment: apparently there is nothing like this by default in the smb.conf. Not even uncommented.

Comment: I agree, it took me hours googling as I remember. It was years back though when I had a cups server serving windows users.